# How to get total number of values in column 1 with order by values in column 2 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Scenario:

```
Column1  Column2
----------------
Test1        5
Test2       10
Test1        5
Test3        5
```

I want to retrieve total number of values in column2 order by values in Column1

Result should be

```
Column1  Column2
----------------
Test1     10
Test2     10
Test3      5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `SUM()` with `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY SUM() DESC`

```
SELECT Column1, SUM(Column2) AS Column2
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Column1
ORDER BY SUM(Column2) DESC, Column1
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c98a0b10617f38bdd9527c4e882c216)

Comment: Thank you very much . i was using order by it gave Test 1 and total of column 2